# A simple representation that satisfies every even perfect number: products over the squarefree parts of its divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, perfect-numbers, divisor-counting-function

I wrote a draft of next statement for even perfect numbers that I believe that isn't in the literatute. I am asking to know a rigorous and simple proof.

> **Question.** Prove that for each fixed even perfect number, denoted with $N=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$, there exist two integers denoted with $A$ and $B$, in fact that those are $$A=\prod_{k=1}^p\operatorname{rad}(d_k)$$
>   and $$B=\prod_{k=1}^p\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{N}{d_k}\right),$$ where $d_k$ denotes the $k$th divisor of $N$ (there are $\sigma_0(N)=2p$)
>   $$1=d_{1}<d_2<\ldots <d_{\frac{\sigma_0(N)}{2}}=2^{p-1}<d_{1+\frac{\sigma_0(N)}{2}}=2^p-1<\ldots <d_{\sigma_0(N)}=N,$$
>   and $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ denotes the radical of the integer $m\geq 1$, see this [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) and such that **then** our even perfect number has the representation $$N=A^{1-\frac{1}{p}}B^{\frac{1}{p}}\tag{1}.$$ **Many thanks.**

Thus I am asking to prove rigorously the statement **then**.

Comment: Of all statements which are not in the literature, some are missing because they are too hard to prove, and some because they are too trivial.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $A $ and $B $ yourself? I don't think you really need any hints for that, you've got all you need in your question already.

Comment: Many thanks for your words @IvanNeretin . Truly I would feel bad if in the future I am annoying some professional mathematician writing here part of his/her work, that's why all my heaviness in my words.

Comment: Okey tomorrow I a going to post myself draft. Sometimes I ask because the feedback of this site is very useful. For example a thing that I didn't ask is if taking an even integer $M$ (but not a perfect square, thus makes sense $\sigma_0(M)=2q$) the fact that $$M=\left(\prod_{k=1}^q\operatorname{rad}(d_k)\right)^{1-\frac{1}{q}}\cdot\left(\prod_{k=1}^q\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{M}{d_k}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ implies that $M$ is an even perfect number, or well there are some special condition on $q$, or well one can find a counterexample. Asking one can obtain more feedback @user8734617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case $p=2$ thus $N=6$ is the first even perfect number is easy.

Thus we consider that $p>2$ and write the divisors as above, after we compute the quantity $\operatorname{rad}(d_k)$, when $1\leq k\leq \frac{\sigma_0(N)}{2}=p$ we conclude that $$A=\prod_{k=1}^p\operatorname{rad}(d_k)=1\cdot(2)^{p-1},\tag{2}$$ and similarly one has that can calculate the factors $\operatorname{rad}(N/d_k)$ as $2(2^p-1)$ if $1\leq k\leq \frac{\sigma_0(N)}{2}-1$ and $\operatorname{rad}(\frac{N}{d_{p}})=2^p-1$ thus $$B=\prod_{k=1}^p\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{N}{d_k}\right)=(2(2^p-1))^{p-1}\cdot(2^p-1)=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)^p.\tag{3}$$
Thus from $(2)$ and $(3)$ one get $(1)$ since $$\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=2^p-1$$
the Mersenne prime associated to the even perfect number $N$.